# Track view Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I have an Android application in which I want to track [views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en). I am not sure if these are considered page views but I don't think they are.

Could someone tell me how to load a tracker so that the events sent would be sent to that specific view?

I have set up the tracking id and other event information.

```
tracker = analytics.newTracker(UA_TRACKER_ID);
tracker.setScreenName(screen);


if (tracker != null) {
    tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    tracker.setScreenName("screen name");
    tracker.setAppName("app name");
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .set("&cs", "campaign source")
            .set("&ck", "campaign stuff")
            .setCategory(category)

            .setAction(action)
            .setLabel(label)
            .build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I was manually setting the campaign source which in turn was resetting my type.

I fixed it by adding

```
.set("&t", "event")
```